# RewriteRule to match the end of a filename

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use URL's like:
`filename_ID.csv` and change the URL to `script.php?id=ID`

What would the regex be to catch the ID after the underscore and pass it to my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is numeric...

```
RewriteRule filename_(\d+)\.csv script.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```